# Installing Eclipse (new) on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been for past day trying to install any newer version of Eclipse than what the Software Center has and every attempt has failed.

I can't seem to follow any given solutions without an error somewhere.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) with mate. I have JavaSDK installed, and I just removed the Software Center version since I saw it was bit old...

All the `gksudo` commands just give me an error and doesn't do anything just says:

```
gedit eclipse.desktop
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "topmenu-gtk-module"
```

I have three different Eclipse install folders extracted to my `/opt` folder, but I can't run any of them, it just says "open" on 2 and in one I can select "run", but it doesn't do anything.

Is there some easy way to install this software? As in note years old version of it?

Comment: Just download and extract the tar file to a folder in your `/home` Dir from the Eclipse website.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you extracted the Eclipse tar files in `/opt`. If yes, then try making the Eclipse file (the one which says 'open') executable with `sudo chmod +x eclipse` in the terminal.